# How to implement both scroll and paint in a sencha touch based application

Tags: sencha-touch-2, html5-canvas, android-browser

I have a sencha touch 2.0 web application which I used on tablet(accessing from website address). It is a small application to paint on a canvas layer over an existing image.

I was unable to scroll the image instead just kept on painting on the canvas when I accessed it from tablet.

In browser I get this scroll bar but on tablet I generally need to touch the image and move it to scroll which doesn't work instead it paints on canvas. How can I have both of them? Is there any work around for this on Android browser?

Comment: maybe you can provide us with some code.. it's not clear what you have overridden..

Comment: Opposite of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567019/paint-on-canvas-in-androids-browser-page-scroll.
Mainly my question is how can I have both scroll and draw without like adding a toggle button(this has very poor ux).